# Investigate linux random number generator in random.c

Tags: linux, random, linux-kernel

I am studying the random number generator in linux kernel before version 3.16

I gain my knowledge from this blog post and by reading the linux source code. 
https://blog.cloudflare.com/ensuring-randomness-with-linuxs-random-number-generator/

I can see the following four functions are contributing to the entropy pool

`add_device_randomness() 
add_interrupt_randomness() 
add_disk_randomness() 
add_input_randomness()`

According to the comment in the source code `add_device_randomness()` is only being used for initialise the entropy pool using hardware identifier, so it is not actually adding randomness to the entropy pool. From what I read, `hwrng` is not adding randomness to the pool in version before 3.16

By reading the source code, we can see the following two functions are controlling the number of entropy bits in the entropy pool.

`credit_entropy_bits() // this is adding entropy bits to the pool 
extract_entropy() // This is removing entropy bits from the pool`

I want to figure out what devices/actions is actually calling these functions and adding entropy to the kernel. Is there anyways to estimate or get a feeling about that?

Comment: You can use a Linux source cross-reference to find the parts of the kernel that call into these functions.  One such component is the core block code: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/blk-core.c?v=3.15#L2465

Comment: Yup, I used that to find out all the `add_randomness()` function references. For `add_device_randomness()`, these are included: fireware, firmware_dmi_scan, ipaq-micro, wm831x-otp, sunxi_sid, rtc-wm831x, rtc-wm831c, tegra20, tegra30, usb, posix-cpu-timer, net-core. Let say my laptop is only using cpu and doesnt have internet connection and other above devices. The only devices that contribute to the randomness is cpu only?

Comment: I think in the last case (bare bones computer) you might also have block core (storage) using it.

Comment: @Timothy - Also see [Analysis of the Linux Random Number Generator](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/086.pdf). If interested, also visit [linux-crypto](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-crypto) on the kernel mailing lists. Things have changed a lot in the 4.x kernels.

Comment: @Peter - *"I think in the last case (bare bones computer) you might also have block core (storage) using it..."* - Linux 3.x kernels decided to stop using IRQ interrupts (removal of the `IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM` flag, without an alternative to gather entropy). Also see [\[PATCH 17/17\] random: final removal of IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1207.2/01043.html).

Comment: @jww Interesting. Good to know.

Comment: @jww The article helps a lot. Even tho it is talking about v2.6.

Comment: @Timothy - If you work on the 4.x kernel, then checkout Stephan Müller's design paper and patches discussed at [Linux Random Number Generator – A New Approach](http://www.chronox.de/lrng/doc/lrng.xhtml). The patches were checked in during the summer of 2016. A search for [Stephan Müller random](https://www.google.com/search?q=Stephan+Müller+random) will turn up lots of hits.

Comment: @jww Im working on linux <3.16 The only thing I cant understand is mix_pool_bytes and credit_entropy. They are using time delta to credit the entropy pool but they are mixing the pool with other data.